# как изменить цвет фона option при наведении мыши

Tags: html, css

делаю combobox с помощью тегов html

```css
select:active, select:focus{
  outline:none
}
```

```html
<select>
      <option value="Гривня">Гривня</option>
      <option value="Долар">Долар</option>
      <option value="Євро">Євро</option>
      <option value="Рубль">Рубль</option>
  </select>
```

как поменять цвет фона при наведении  мыши на один из  option и как отключить фокус выпадающего меню , я убрала фокус самого select, но это не все что нужно

Comment: Возможно вам поможет, сам не раз пользовался данным плагином для select - option, очень прост в установке
https://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать вот такой код, как видим на хроме это не работает.

```css
option:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<select>
      <option value="Гривня">Гривня</option>
      <option value="Долар">Долар</option>
      <option value="Євро">Євро</option>
      <option value="Рубль">Рубль</option>
  </select>
```

Вот аналогичный вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover

Пройдясь по ответам понимаем что так сделать нельзя.

Единственным решением это создать свой компонент, который имитирует работу select-а, со своими стилями. Как вариант использовать готовый библиотечный компонент, который без труда можно найти в интернете.

Comment: Дополню. Можно также использовать решение на jQuery, например: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: А в каких браузерах работает? У меня и в `FF` не сработало....

Comment: заработало только в `EDGE && IE`

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. Подскажу вам один плагин "jQuery Formstyler". Очень удобный и необходимый, как я считаю, плагин для профессиональной верстки. С помощью него можно изменить как вам угодно checkbox, radio, select и т.д.... Почитайте о нем подробнее в интернете. С помощью этого плагина вы можете изменить фон option по "щелчку пальцев"